# ActiveAdmin admin_users table devise users table logging in issue

Tags: devise, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Following is my setup

- devise (4.4.3)
- activeadmin (1.3.0)
- Rails 5.2

**I created a user table with devise. installed active admin and used the normal method and created admin_users table. NO I AM NOT USING THE SAME TABLE. THESE ARE DIFFERENT TABLES (I had to do this cause last time this question was marked as duplicate cause the user thought i used the same table)**

Routes file looks like this:

```
devise_for :users
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

devise_scope :user do
 authenticated :user do
  root 'home#dashboard', as: :authenticated_root
 end

 unauthenticated do
  root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
 end
end
```

Now the issue is root_path '/' redirects correctly and I am able to login as User. But I am not able to login as Admin. It redirects me back to root_path that is unauthenticated user.

But weirdly when I login as user, I can then login as admin_user.

**AGAIN I AM USING DIFFERENT TABLES, admin_users and users**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you an easy way to add admin in devise

```
$rails g migration add_admin_to_user
```

in the db

```
 def change
    add_column :users, :admin , :boolean , {default: false}
  end
```

in user.rb

```
  def admin?
    admin
  end

<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
<% end %>
```

then i do sign up from the email that i want to be the admin

then in rails c select the email that you want it to be the admin for example

```
User.last
user=User.last
user.admin=true
user
user.save
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But this is a alternate solution. I am looking for why active_admin normal installation wont work with devise and user normal installation. Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this.

So the issue is when you have activeadmin admin_users and users table that is created with devise, and you place the authenticated_user! before_action in application_controller, activeadmin interprets it as authorization failure(though this should not be the case).

Solution to this is, go to active_admin.rb and add the following code

```
config.skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
```

This forces activeadmin to listen to only its authrization_adapter.